# iPhone 6 media query shows in simulator not in phone

Tags: ios, css, iphone, media-queries

Since I don't have access to all phone models, I often use simulators, especially the one that comes with XCode. I'm finding that my media query for iPhone 6 is working perfectly in the simulator, but not in actual phones... or at least the one my client has. I've had her clear the cache and checked she has the most recent version.

Here's a link to the page: http://muirheadfoods.com/fruit-butters.php. Properly displayed on simulator:

[image]

Her phone shows much tighter spacing and - more importantly - the image right below the menu button is not visible at all.

I'm using a very standard media query:

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 
}
```

Any thoughts on what it might be? I'm baffled.

Thanks - Joe

Comment: Can you tell me which simulator you are using ?

Comment: The Apple version found in the latest XCode, but I've also checked on 3 other online simulators, including Chrome.

Comment: Could it be her browser? Are you propperly resetting the default styles of the browsers? Like this: * { margin: 0, padding: 0 }

Comment: You can use the google chrome inspector tool to simulate devices.

Comment: @TuomasKoivisto - that wouldn't account for the image not showing the div or other styles - some set to !important - not being depicted. It's really ignoring everything in the style sheet.

Comment: @TimGerhard - yeah, I know I tried. It shows the same as the iOS simulator.